# $k$ -center with outliers - but the points are on a line

Tags: algorithms, graphs, approximation, clustering

The classic $k$-center with outliers problem is NP-hard and there exist approximation algorithms to solve it.

However, what if we assume that the input point are on a line, rather than in an arbitrary metric space?

Does the problem become polytime solvable? Can someone link me to reading on this topic?

Comment: Can you give a self-contained definition of the "classic k-center with outliers" problem?  I know what the k-center problem is, but I'm not sure how the "with outliers" part changes the problem definition.  In any case, have you tried sorting the points and applying dynamic programming?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/96052/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/41332/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.